# Symfony: Rewriting to automatic wiring when DB information is specified in getManager

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony 3.4 supports rewriting of container->get().
I was changing get("doctrine")->getManager(), but there was a place where information was passed in () to getManager as shown below.
In such a case, how should I rewrite it?

**Problem Code**

```
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get("doctrine")->getManager('mkt');
        $this->conn = $em->getConnection();
     }
```

**Normal changes**
Before

```php
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get("doctrine")->getManager('mkt');
        $this->conn = $em->getConnection();
    }
```

After

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
class ~
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        parent::__construct();
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->conn = $this->em->getConnection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is working with multiple Entity Managers, you can inject a specific one like this:

```
 App\Service\YouServices:
    arguments:
        $entityManager: '@doctrine.orm.mkt_entity_manager'
```

Haven't tried this yet so have a look at: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: Thank you. The answer helped me. By the way, in the case of ```->getManager(self::DB_CONNECT)```, how should I register?